# 'Error adding system: Data not available.' fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I've set up a system where upon walking into an object the scene changes, although when that happens 2 errors pop up: 'GI output for inputsystem: XXXX is missing' and 'Error adding system: Data not available.' The scene is also pitch black when loaded. Any solutions?